# Access a field in Method of a Generic

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am writing my first generic Class in C#. in General I am doing this

```
switch (allValidatedCombo[i].Name.ToString())
{
     case "senderComboBox":
           senderComboBox.SelectedIndex = senderComboBox.FindString(senderComboBox.Text);
           List<Provider> allProviders = senderComboBox.DataSource as List<Provider>;
           var item1 = allProviders.Where(x => x.Id == (short)senderComboBox.SelectedValue).SingleOrDefault();
           criteria = " SenderId ='" + item1.Id + "' and "; 
           break;
     case "receiverComboBox":
          receiverComboBox.SelectedIndex = receiverComboBox.FindString(receiverComboBox.Text);
          List<Provider> allProviders1 = receiverComboBox.DataSource as List<Provider>;
          var item2 = allProviders1.Where(x => x.Id == (short)receiverComboBox.SelectedValue).SingleOrDefault();
          criteria = " RecipientId ='" + item2.Id + "' and ";
     break;
     case "signedByComboBox":
          signedByComboBox.SelectedIndex = signedByComboBox.FindString(signedByComboBox.Text);
          List<User> allUsers1 = receiverComboBox.DataSource as List<User>;
          var item3 = allUsers1.Where(x => x.Id == (short)receiverComboBox.SelectedValue).SingleOrDefault();
          criteria = " SignedById ='" + item3.Id + "' and ";
     break;
     case "registeredByComboBox":
          registeredByComboBox.SelectedIndex = registeredByComboBox.FindString(registeredByComboBox.Text);
          List<User> allUsers2 = registeredByComboBox.DataSource as List<User>;
          var item4 = allUsers2.Where(x => x.Id == (short)receiverComboBox.SelectedValue).SingleOrDefault();
          criteria = " CreatedById ='" + item4.Id + "' and ";
      break;
 }
```

So I decided to make it generic. I did this

```
public class HelperGeneric<T>
{
    public List<T> genericProperty { get; set; }
    public short genericSelectedvalue { get; set; }

    public void Method<T>(T input)
    {  
        genericProperty.Where(x => x.Id == genericSelectedvalue).SingleOrDefault();
    }
}
```

This is how I call it:

```
 HelperGeneric<Provider> helper = new HelperGeneric<Provider>();
 helper.genericProperty = senderComboBox.DataSource as List<Provider>;
 helper.genericSelectedvalue = (short)senderComboBox.SelectedValue;
 helper.Method(senderComboBox.DataSource as List<Provider>);
```

But in LINQ of Method

```
public void Method<T>(T input)
{  
    return genericProperty.Where(x => x.Id == genericSelectedvalue).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

I can not access `x.Id`. How can return a record and setting a condition for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an `interface` with one `property`:

```
public interface IContainId
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And then your generic class and the `Provider` class should implement this interface, something like the following:

```
public class HelperGeneric<T> where T : class , IContainId

public class Provider : IContainId
```

Then the following should works fine:

```
genericProperty.Where(x => x.Id == genericSelectedvalue)
```

Comment: Note that class `Provider` now has to implement this `IContainId` interface as well